# Using Max in LINQ query - null values in the list

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to get a Max value (of SecKey), becuase I have a null value for one of the item the Linq result is giving me first value (in this case it is 40). SecKey value should be 200. How do I fix this?

I have tried this

```
SecKey = groupedList.Max(d => string.IsNullOrEmpty(d.SecKey) ? "0" : d.SecKey)
```

but no use!

```
var newData = from list in myList
    group list by new { list.BadgeNum, list.ActiveDate, list.EndDate }
        into groupedList
        select new
        {
            groupedList.Key.BadgeNum,
            groupedList.Key.ActiveDate,
            groupedList.Key.EndDate,
            Amount = groupedList.Sum(a => a.Amount)
            SecKey = groupedList.Max(d => d.SecKey)
        };
```

This is data I have in myList

```
BadgeNum    ActiveDate  EndDate Amount  SecKey
722711      1/1/2014    1/31/2014   10  40
722711      1/1/2014    1/31/2014   10  
722711      1/1/2014    1/31/2014   70  200
```

**Current Output:**

```
BadgeNum    ActiveDate  EndDate Amount  SecKey
722711      1/1/2014    1/31/2014   90  40
```

**Expected Output:**

```
BadgeNum    ActiveDate  EndDate Amount  SecKey
722711      1/1/2014    1/31/2014   90  200
```

Comment: Is SecKey a String or numeric type?

Comment: Have you tried: **SecKey = groupedList.Max(d => <int>d.SecKey)**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This does not happen because you have `null`s in the list - `Max` would ignore them.

The problem is that the data type that you are using for your `SecKey` sorts `40` ahead of `200`. This can happen, for example, if you use strings for `SecKey`, in which case `'200'` would come lexicographically *earlier* than `'40'`.

If you have no control over the data type, you could work around this issue by ordering your group by cast to `int` in ascending order, and taking the last element (or ordering in descending order and taking the first element), like this:

```
SecKey = groupedList.OrderBy(d => Convert.ToInt32(d.SecKey)).Last().SecKey;
```

Comment: make sense.. let me change the datatype